# How to read a file and sum the number of that file in php

Tags: php

Let's say you have a file with the following structure: txt format

```
"id,name,value
1,Dan,150
2,Peter,300
3,Mark,400
4,Victor,600"
```

This function I used to read the file :

```
function readAFile()
{

    $userfileInfo = fopen("peopleInformation.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open the file.");
    //echo fread($userfileInfo, filesize("peopleInformation.txt"));
    $theData = fread($userfileInfo, filesize("peopleInformation.txt"));
    echo $theData;
    fclose($userfileInfo);
}
```

Output:

```
"id,name,value 1,Dan,150 2,Peter,300 3,Mark,400 4,Victor,600"
```

How  i will seperate 150, 300, 400, 600 and sum them in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `preg_match_all` and RegEx

```html
function readAFile()
{

    $userfileInfo = fopen("peopleInformation.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open the file.");
    //echo fread($userfileInfo, filesize("peopleInformation.txt"));
    $theData = fread($userfileInfo, filesize("peopleInformation.txt"));
    echo $theData;
    preg_match_all('/\d+,.+,(\d+)/', $theData, $output);
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($output[1] as $value){
        $sum = $sum + (int) $value;
    };
    //echo "Sum :".$sum;
    fclose($userfileInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a csv file, you can explode each line with `,` and sum the last item except the first header line.

```
$lines = file($file_path);
$lines = array_map(function($v){return explode(",",$v);},array_slice($lines,1));
echo array_sum(array_column($lines,2)) . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgets` function to read it line by it. Then you can easily use `explode` function to change the line into array. The last index in the array is your desired value.
something like below:

```
$theData = fopen("peopleInformation.txt", "rw"); 
fgets($theData); //skip the header.
$sum = 0;
while (! feof ($my_file)) 
  { 
   $line = fgets($theData); 
   $array_val = explode($line);
   $sum += (int)end($array_val);
  }
```